# can not run a sql file windows command line using SOURCE command

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

hi i am using `windows 7, xampp`

. i am trying to run a `sql` file using `CMD` ut it gives me an error

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\x'.
```

this is what i am doing

[image]

this command is not working

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs\elephanti2\db\mas_gis_city_ip.sql;
```

*** one other problem with this works fine when i tried by go to `phpmyadmin` and import the file .

why this happening , i have no idea , please help ..................

Comment: What is the contents of your .sql file?

Comment: actually this happening for every sql file , not only this file . but every file works fin when import by phpmyadmin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My original answer:

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\elephanti2\\db\\mas_gis_city_ip.sql;
```

You could also try executing the command like this:

```
mysql> SOURCE C:/xampp/htdocs/elephanti2/db/mas_gis_city_ip.sql;
```

(Source: a comment in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) suggests using forward slashes on Windows machines)

Comment: Yep, and remember ***not*** to include quotes around the path, which also tripped me up.

Comment: Strange enough, I had to remove the semi-colon to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting your file name.  Notice your command:

> mysql> SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs...

is probably being interpreted as:

> mysql SOURCE C: \xampp \htdocs...

(see the \x there?)

If you quote the file name, I bet it'll work.  (not sure if mysql requires ' or " for quoting filenames in this context, try both)

Answer (score 2):

Actually this worked. I think it is dwuff's previous answer.

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\elephanti2\\db\\mas_gis_city_ip.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently trying to install FossTrak, and this was the syntax that worked on windows 10, with Mysql 5.7

`\. C:/share/epcis-repository-0.5.0/epcis_schema.sql`

using `\source`  did not, and neither did `\\`, and by accident i removed the `;` and it worked.